# Swagger ui is shows empty object in model

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using springboot and added swagger 3.0.0 dependency
When I run swagger ui model class is showing empty on ui and documentation pages.
I am using annotation to define swagger

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey when I run swagger URL on local port ui page is loading with all the configuration that are set  but inside model section I am getting empty value {}

Comment: I think I'm late to the problem but I just solved it in my case, the problem was due to the following configuration in the properties

lazy-initialization I had it in true, I passed it to false and it works
spring:
   main:
     lazy-initialization: false

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Example Value Schema, please check your required object if you have getters and setters implemented.

Comment: Hi,  I have getter setter implemented

Comment: Please edit your question if you can and add some photos it would help me to find the problem